# Salesforce-Heroku Dataclip Integration

Tags: rest-api, rest, heroku, heroku-connect

I am integration Salesforce with Heroku.I have create the sql query in Heroku Dataclip to get the JSON.
My SQL query :

> SELECT ent.tech_assessment_token AS Assess_TOKEN,ent.stage As stage,
>   ent.created_at,ent.updated_at FROM entries ent limit 4;

The JSON create is not in Key:Value formmat,because of which its difficult for me to parse further in Rest Apex class.
Following my JSON generated :

> {"title":"Test Data Clip","fields":["assess_token","stage","created_at","updated_at"],"types":[1043,23,1114,1114],"type_names":["text","integer","unknown","unknown"],"values":[["a7063e277631887fc81e0ed9a3a437f5",6,"2016-08-17 16:46:22.615632","2016-09-28 19:13:00.94779"],["015e760aa9c5abf8a22a817f54ca248e",1,"2016-08-17 18:57:52.508419","2016-08-18 11:49:44.470628"],["83d9b617120d0299bc0e0c3ef0397752",6,"2016-08-17 17:08:17.087928","2016-09-28 19:15:31.672807"],["a83d6e8a97616697e94ce2bcaa6e73ba",0,"2016-08-17 19:35:31.356247","2016-09-13 13:26:58.707726"]]}

Is there any way to change the input JSON format in Heroku app itself? Or do I need to modify my parsing logic in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json2apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) to generate a file that you can use to parse your output. When I tried it, it came up with the following Apex Code:

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class JSON2Apex {

    public String title;
    public List<String> fields;
    public List<Integer> types;
    public List<String> type_names;
    public List<List<String>> values;


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

You can safely ignore "types", as it is not really useful as is, but by using "fields", "type_names" and "values", you can pretty easily parse out what's left:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> parsedObjects = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
for(String[] item: result.values) {
    Map<String, Object> itemData = new Map<String, Object>();
    for(Integer index = 0, size = result.fields.size(), index < size; index++) {
        itemData.put(result.fields[index], item[index]);
    }
    parsedObjects.add(itemData);
}
```

At this point, all that's left is to figure out how to parse the various attributes, which result.type_names[index] can solve inside the loop (which is why I used "Object" instead of "String" for the map value).